# change path for file to copy in other path

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, filepath, fs

I use the following API to copy file to specific folder (which is working)

```
ncp(folderPath,__dirname + "/newfolder", function (err) {
....
```

https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp

> c:\Users\WebstormProjects\NodeParent\node_modules\samplenodeapp\controller

The problem is that this create for me a folder inside the `controller` of   samplenodeapp(since the above code inside the controller) and I want it to create it one level up I mean

instead

```
samplenodeapp
 -controller
   -newFolder
```

I want

```
samplenodeapp
 -controller
 -newFoler
```

That the new folder will be in the same level of the controller,how its recommended to do it ?

of course I can split the value but there is better way to do it?

I mean if there is better way then the following

```
var localPath = __dirname;

localPath = localPath.substr(0, localPath.lastIndexOf("\\"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `path.join`

```
var path = require('path');
var destination = path.join(__dirname,'../newfolder');
ncp(folderPath,destination, function (err) {
...
```